# Powermock Compatibility with JDK 17

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, powermockito, java-17

Recently I was upgrading my project from JDK 11 to JDK 17. After upgrading, powermock seems to have an issue. While running AUT's , I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PowerMock internal error: Should never throw exception at this level
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3fc34119
```

Do you know any workaround this issue, If so can you please provide the solution.

Comment: Have you taken a look if there are newer versions of powermockito that might be required for more recent versions of java?

Comment: Could it be that you encountered open issue [1099](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1099) and/or [1094](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1094)?

Comment: I am using the latest 2.0.9 powermock version

Comment: If you want to stay up-to-date with recent JDK versions, I suggest to stay with mockito. Historically, Powermock has taken longer time to keep up, while mockito has a bigger ecosystem around it, both in terms of users and developers.

Comment: After encountering this incompatibility once again, I've used it as an opportunity to review whether I truly needed Powermock. In my case, I was only using it for mocking static classes, which is since supported in Mockito.

Answer (score 26):

As a stop gap measure (until Powermock gets updated), you should be able to run your tests by passing the following argument to your JVM:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

If you're running your tests with `Maven`, you can configure the `surefire-plugin` like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${plugin.surefire.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Also you can use these:   
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.base=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Worked for me (JDK 17)

Comment: how to use it in gradle?

Comment: @ImtiazAli this worked for me: test {  jvmArgs "--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" }

Comment: How to make this work in case I want to run the tests in Intellij? 
In other words, if I right click on the test class, then I click run, it will still throw the exception mentioned above.

Comment: @MA1 If you re using gradle check my answer.

Comment: @MA I am also facing while debugging with intellij. Can you tell me if you got any success

Answer (score 13):

This shoudl allow the solution to work with tests ran from inside the IDE, Android Studio in my case.

I had to do this because PowerMock doesn't play nice with Java 17 on Android.

In your top level project build.gradle, at the bottom just add

```
subprojects{
    tasks.withType(Test).configureEach{
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs + ['--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED']
    }
}
```

If you are using Kotlin for your Gradle files see
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f9901627431be098ad73abd725fbb3738747461c/build.gradle.kts#L153

Comment: this is a great answer, it fixed Android Studio and my failing Jenkins build!

Comment: It works for Robolectric too. Thanks