# How to mock protected super class method from external dependency

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am trying to test a method, which internaly calls a protected method from the parent class (**external dependency**).

Consider this simplified example:

```
public class Parent {

    protected void parentAction() {
        System.out.println("Parent action");
    }
}
```

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private final Runnable backupAction;
    private final Runnable normalAction;

    public Child(Runnable backupAction, Runnable normalAction) {
        this.backupAction = backupAction;
        this.normalAction = normalAction;
    }

    public void childAction() {
        try {
            super.parentAction();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            this.backupAction.run();
            return;
        }
        this.normalAction.run();
    }
}
```

I want to test that in case of exception, the backup action is invoked, while the normal one is not - this is easy enough using `verify()`. The prerequisite for that is mocking `super.parentAction()` to throw exception.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/17795888) is not applicable for my use case, because the parent class is an external dependency and I don't have access to the package (I can't make the same package in the test folder).

Comment: Not an answer, but usually tests like what you are trying to implement provide very little value and end up being brittle (as it depends on an external library). It's usually better to test these classes with an [integration test](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000772.html), which do use the actual external component and ensures the code works by removing any assumption of how the 3rd party library works.

Comment: @Augusto I am not making assumptions here, the test only verifies that if `super.parentAction();` throws, the backup logic will be invoked, instead of the normal one.

Comment: So, I only have 2 scenarios, `super` throws, or executes succesfully. I am not mocking, and I don't need to mock, anything which might be done, or not done by `super`.

Comment: does the `Child` class have to be a subclass of `Parent`? I.e., can you rewrite it to use composition and stub the `Parent` class to throw an exception or do something successfully?

Comment: @user2340612 `Child` has to be a `Parent` and is one (the `is a` relation is correct). An implementation like proposed certainly is possible, but undesirable. I would need, let's call it `ParentExtension` in order to invoke the protected method trough a public one. Then `Child` needs to both depend on `ParentExtension` and extend `Parent`.

Comment: I see. Is there anything that influences `parentAction`? For example, does it take any input parameter that you can supply in your tests to cause success & failure scenarios?

Comment: @user2340612 No, unfortunately the method does not have any parameters. I can build the object manually, with mocked dependencies, configured in a way that causes exception, but that's more complicated and probably brittle way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints you have to follow, I think one option could be to create test-specific implementations that override the `parentAction` to cover the specific use cases.

```kotlin
class ChildTest {

    private Runnable normalAction = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class);
    private Runnable backupAction = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldUseNormalWhenNoExceptionThrown() {

        Child child = new Child(normalAction, backupAction) {
            @Override
            protected void parentAction() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("invoked");
            }
        };
        child.childAction();

        Mockito.verify(normalAction).run();
        Mockito.verify(backupAction, never()).run();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUseBackupWhenExceptionThrown() {

        Child child = new Child(normalAction, backupAction) {

            @Override
            public void childAction() {
                super.childAction();
            }

            @Override
            protected void parentAction() throws Exception {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        };
        child.childAction();

        Mockito.verify(backupAction).run();
        Mockito.verify(normalAction, never()).run();
    }
}
```

Please note that this requires changing your `Child` class to avoid calling `super.parentAction()`, but to use just `parentAction()` instead – otherwise it'll always invoke the method from `Parent` instead of the implementation from the test:

```kotlin
public void childAction() {
    try {
        parentAction();
        this.normalAction.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.backupAction.run();
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can use PowerMock to mock the protected method:

```kotlin
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Child.class})
class ChildTest {

    private Runnable normalAction = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class);
    private Runnable backupAction = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldUseNormalWhenNoExceptionThrown() throws Exception {

        Child child = PowerMockito.spy(new Child(normalAction, backupAction));
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(child, "parentAction", new Object[] {});

        child.childAction();

        Mockito.verify(normalAction).run();
        Mockito.verify(backupAction, never()).run();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUseBackupWhenExceptionThrown() throws Exception {

        Child child = PowerMockito.spy(new Child(normalAction, backupAction));
        doThrow(new Exception()).when(child, "parentAction");
        child.childAction();

        Mockito.verify(backupAction).run();
        Mockito.verify(normalAction, never()).run();
    }
}
```

However, note that if you're using JDK17+ you need to specify extra argument to the compiler – see [Powermock Compatibility with JDK 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896191/powermock-compatibility-with-jdk-17)

Comment: PowerMock looks promising, but which dependency exactly should i use for junit5? I remember reading, that it is not yet compatible with junit5 (no runner).

Comment: I'm afraid PowerMock doesn't support Junit 5 yet. There's a [community PR](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/pull/1146) that was opened in February this year, however I'm not sure if PowerMock is still maintained, as the most recent commit is from February 2022