# Stubbing a protected method of a base class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using a third-party library, which has an abstract base class that the application code is supposed to extend. The subclass can then call a protected method on the base class as part of its processing. Whether that is good design or not can be discussed, but that's how it is. I want to test my subclass in isolation, and therefore stub the protected method of the base class.

I can create a Mockito spy for an instance of the subclass, and then stub out public methods of the ABC. However, this does not work for the protected one, since the following obviously is not permitted:

```java
MySubclass obj = Mockito.spy(new MySubclass());
Mockito.when(obj.protectedMethod()).thenReturn(42); // error: protectedMethod() has protected access in AbstractBaseClass
```

Is there some other way of specifying a stub for that method?

Comment: I had the same situation some time ago - [How to mock protected super class method from external dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214908/how-to-mock-protected-super-class-method-from-external-dependency). It seems that at the moment the only option for mocking is powermock, if junit < 5.

Comment: Thank you! This is close to how we used to do it, but we´re transitioning away from PowerMock as part of upgrading the code base to Java 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using the following:

```java
MySubclass obj = Mockito.spy(new MySubclass());

Mockito.when(obj.publicMethod()).thenReturn(5);

InvocationContainerImpl container = MockUtil.getInvocationContainer(obj);
InvocationFactory invocationFactory = new DefaultInvocationFactory();
Invocation invocation = invocationFactory.createInvocation(
    obj, new MockSettingsImpl<MySubclass>(),
    AbstractBaseClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("protectedMethod"), () -> null
);
container.resetInvocationForPotentialStubbing(new InvocationMatcher(invocation));
container.addAnswer(i -> 4, Strictness.LENIENT);

Assertions.assertEquals(9, obj.sum());
```

It´s not very pretty, but when hidden behind a helper method, it´s not *that* bad. It uses classes from packages under `org.mockito.internal`, but they are documented as part of the public API.

Answer (score 2):

Like you say yourself, that's pretty much a result of bad design. What I suppose you can do is make the method `public` in the extended class, spy it, then mock the method.

```
class BaseClass {
 protected Result protectedMethod() {
  //
 }
}
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
 public Result protectedMethod() {
  return super.protectedMethod();
 }
}
```

That should allow the mocking you do.

Note that it is generally advised not to use spys at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! While that is possible, it means changing production code to fit a test, which I´d like to avoid, as that is (to me, at least) bad practice.

Comment: @MagnusReftel I agree. However, a) there's already inheritance instead of composition, and b) you already spy a subject under test, so it doesn't seem like your project shys away from bad practices :P

Comment: The choice of inheritance here was made by the author of the third-party library, not us. Given the constraints, I don´t see why using a spy to separate the code under test from its dependency would be bad practice.

Comment: Well let me know if you find another solution ^^

Comment: Sure! I´ll post the answer here if I find one.

Comment: Did find a way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074377/2931171

Answer (score 1):

According to my own question some time ago - [How to mock protected super class method from external dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214908/how-to-mock-protected-super-class-method-from-external-dependency), it seems that at the moment this is only possible with powermock and junit version before 5.

As a workaround (and probably less bad practices used) you can refactor your own class to delegate the operation of the protected method to another dependency, which you will mock. Consider this example parent class:

```
public abstract class Parent {

  public int incrementResult() {
    return doStuffInternal() + 1;
  }

  protected abstract int doStuffInternal();
}
```

In the child class `doStuffInternal()` will be implemented to depend on another class to do the actual work:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

  private final IntSupplier intSupplier;

  public Child(IntSupplier intSupplier) {
    this.intSupplier = intSupplier;
  }

  @Override
  protected int doStuffInternal() {
    return this.intSupplier.getAsInt();
  }
}
```

In the test, mock the dependency and verify that the mock has been used:

```
public class MyTests {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    IntSupplier mock = mock(IntSupplier.class);
    when(mock.getAsInt()).thenReturn(10);

    Child child = new Child(mock);
    int actual = child.incrementResult();
    assertEquals(11, actual, "Incorrect increment result");

    verify(mock).getAsInt();
  }
}
```